# Forbid GCC to generate call instruction as last instruction of function

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, assembly, backtrace

After switching to GCC 4.8, we noticed that the code of some functions ends in a call instruction, like this:

```
0000000000000167 <function_a>:
 167:   55                      push   %rbp
 168:   89 fe                   mov    %edi,%esi
 16a:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 171 <function_a+0xa>
                        16d: R_X86_64_PC32      .LC0-0x4
 171:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 173:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 176:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  17b <function_a+0x14>
                        177: R_X86_64_PLT32     function_c-0x4
 17b:   48 8d 0d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rcx        # 182 <function_a+0x1b>
                        17e: R_X86_64_PC32      .rodata+0x6afc
 182:   48 8d 35 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rsi        # 189 <function_a+0x22>
                        185: R_X86_64_PC32      .LC1-0x4
 189:   48 8d 3d 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(%rip),%rdi        # 190 <function_a+0x29>
                        18c: R_X86_64_PC32      .LC2-0x4
 190:   ba 88 00 00 00          mov    $0x88,%edx
 195:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  19a <function_b>
                        196: R_X86_64_PLT32     __assert_fail-0x4

000000000000019a <function_b>:                                            
 19a:   55                      push   %rbp
 ...
```

Our program tries to collect backtrace in case of some faulty situations, but our algorithm is broken in such cases, because the return address belongs to another function.

Is there a way to forbid GCC to generate this type of function end?

Comment: It probably happens because `__assert_fail` is marked as `noreturn` so the compiler doesn't bother generating further code. The `call` itself is of course valid, since the source probably uses a function call, such as `if (!condition) __assert_fail(foo);` Not sure how it messes up anything.

Comment: You could try `-fno-optimize-sibling-calls`.  I don't know if it will work but it might.